# How to solve Invalid comparison?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def show_entry_fields():
    print("Bit Diameter as cms: %s\nWell Name: %s" % (e1.get(), e2.get()))

master = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(master, 
         text="Bit Diameter as cms").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(master, 
         text="Well Name").grid(row=1)

e1 = tk.Entry(master)
e2 = tk.Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

tk.Button(master, 
          text='Quit', 
          command=master.quit).grid(row=3, 
                                    column=0, 
                                    sticky=tk.W, 
                                    pady=4)
tk.Button(master, 
          text='Show', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, 
                                                       column=1, 
                                                       sticky=tk.W, 
                                                       pady=4)

tk.mainloop()


import tkinter.filedialog

file = filedialog.askopenfilename()

if file:
        try:
            filename = r"{}".format(file)
            df = pd.read_excel(file)
        except ValueError:
            label.config(text="File could not be opened")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            label.config(text="File Not Found")
                         


data = df.loc[df['WELL'] == 'V131B'][['DEPTH_MD', 'CALIPER', 'GR', 'LITHOLOGY', 'SHALLOW', 'DEEP']]

df.loc[(df.GR < 30.0000) & (df.CALIPER > 'e1') & (df.SHALLOW > 2.60000)  , "LITHOLOGY"] = '1' 
df.loc[(df.GR > 100.0000) , "LITHOLOGY"] = '3' 
df.LITHOLOGY.fillna('2', inplace=True)

df


app_root.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to create an interface for taking data from user. As you can see, I want user to write a value which I defined as e1. The problem is when I try to connect this with my data frame, It gives `TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=float64 and str` .

How can I solve the problem in this line? `df.loc[(df.GR < 30.0000) & (df.CALIPER > 'e1') & (df.SHALLOW > 2.60000)  , "LITHOLOGY"] = '1'`

Edit: I changed the type of e1 as `print("Bit Diameter as cms: %s\nWell Name: %s" % (float(e1.get()), e2.get()))` but still I have problems. I cannot use e1 as I want.

Comment: still a current problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @cls said you are comparing a float to **the string** 'e1' in `(df.CALIPER > 'e1')`.  You need to compare df.CALIPER to `float( e1.get() )`.  I don't have access to your files so I've not shown a second gui just a print statement.  As the first GUI will be destroyed after the quit `e1.get()` must be executed before destroying the application with the result stored for later access.

```
import tkinter as tk

def show_entry_fields():
    print("Bit Diameter as cms: %s\nWell Name: %s" % (e1.get(), e2.get()))

master = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(master, 
         text="Bit Diameter as cms").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(master, 
         text="Well Name").grid(row=1)

e1 = tk.Entry(master)
e2 = tk.Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

e1_float = 0.0          # Storage for results on exit
e2_string = ""          # Storage for results on exit

def get_float( entry ):
    """ Converts the characters in an Entry to a float, 
        returns 0.0 if not a valid float"""
    try: 
        return float( entry.get() )
    except ValueError:
        return 0.0

def save_and_quit():
    global e1_float, e2_string
    e1_float = get_float( e1 )
    e2_string = e2.get()
    print( type( 'e1'),  'e1', type(e1), e1 )   # Prints to see what happens.
    print( type( e1.get()), e1.get(), type(e1_float), e1_float )
    master.destroy()

tk.Button(master, 
          text='Save & Quit', 
          command=save_and_quit).grid(row=3, 
                                      column=0, 
                                      sticky=tk.W, 
                                      pady=4)
tk.Button(master, 
          text='Show', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, 
                                                       column=1, 
                                                       sticky=tk.W, 
                                                       pady=4)

tk.mainloop()

print("Bit Diameter as cms: %s\nWell Name: %s" % (e1_float, e2_string))
```

Comment: I guess Im doing something wrong. Because It still gives TclError: invalid command name ".!entry" error.

Comment: (df.CALIPER > e1_float) this solved the problem. Thanks!